# Selecting Cell in table based on specific criteria for both row and column

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm new to Excel and VBA, and I'm wondering if what I would like to do is possible, and how I can go about doing it.

I have a large table with two main criteria: Month and Name.

```
           January                     February

Name      Set A   Set B  Set C      Set A  Set B  Set C      

Frank       1       2      3          4      5      6

Harry       2       4      6          3      6      9

Sally       12      24     12         2      4       2
```

I need to be able to set the row (ex. Frank, Harry, or Sally), and the month that I'm working on (ex. February) and then paste values into Set A, Set B and Set C etc from another worksheet.

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Edit your question with what you have and we can help correct it or point you in a better direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for INDEX (Application.Index) and MATCH (Applicaiton.Match). They return row and column numbers that you can use to build cell locations.

There's a pretty good example here http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=522804

If you are able to modify your month names to duplicate in each column, it will probably make your life easier.

The trick is going to be matching the set and month to get the proper column. Here's an example of using an if statement around index/match to solve a problem like your month/set issue. http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?p=233645#239180'

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response, but I don't exactly follow.  What does the index and match functions do?

Comment: Microsoft can explain it much better than I can. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214142 This will help you find cells based on "Frank"&&"January"&&"Set A" in whatever worksheet

Comment: It would be helpful if you quoted relevant pieces of information from those links in case they move or die in the future.